# How to close a subprocess opened with Popen?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below python 3.6 code that successfully opens a ping command and executes without a problem. I noticed that it seems like there's a "ping" process in my Task Manager that lingers.

Code:

```
ping = subprocess.Popen("ping -n {} -w {} {}".format(5, 3, ip), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Question:

Do I have to explicitly "close" this subprocess? And if so, is there a way to do this with a "with" block so that it closes automatically when it's returned/finished? ...Or, does Popen not require an explicit closure of the subprocess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Popen.terminte()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) is what you're looking for. From documentation:

> Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function TerminateProcess() is called to stop the child.

Comment: Is this also implicitly done when the process "returns" (in my case the result of the ping command)?

Comment: As far as I understand you need `subprocess.run()` which will run your process and terminate it.